# My webapp as a shortcut won't open in a dedicated window on Chrome (Android)

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

The title may be confusing. Let me explain :

When you open a website in Chrome in Android you can create a shortcut to the page clicking the three dot icon in the top right corner, after choosing "add to Home Screen".

For some website/webapp the shortcut acts as a standalone app starter. In other words it opens in a dedicated container in Android and if you were to tap the shortcut again the app wouldn't open twice, instead it is aware a container already exist and send it to the front (only one instance).
It is as if Chrome recognizes the website as an app.

But for my webapp it doesn't work. If I make a shortcut on the home screen and tap it, the page opens in a new tab in the main Chrome instance. This webpage/webapp is supposed to be standalone, there is no point to have multiple instance of it in the browser. Ideally when I tap the shortcut Chrome should open the app in its dedicated app window (to avoid clogging the tab list uselessly.)

Does anyone know how to circumvent this problem? Are there some instructions to add in the HTML to force Chrome to recognize the page as an "app" and make use of its own container?

---

As I write this question I believe this has something to do with Progressive Web App, Chrome only accepts to "install" your website as an app shortcut if it follows a certain format.
But also my app doesn't need to implement all these progressive features, it's just a simple app that only myself is using.
So if you know how to force Chrome to produce this effect without writing a lot of code I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

It does need to be a PWA. Here are [the requirements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs#requirements).